# Difference between Intel and AMD chips?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to know if there is a big dig difference between Intel and AMD chips in terms of how sql behaves?  I've been told that their is a big difference between the chips depending on application.  Is there any way I can test or someone can advise me on how I can go about troubleshooting this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have explicit advice for you, but read / listen: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/glennberry/2012/09/12/interview-on-runasradio-281-with-richard-campbell/ You'll also note that Glenn typically recommends Intel even though AMD chips are cheaper *and* there is a significant licensing discount for SQL Server 2012 as well.

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, recent Intel processors perform better on most SQL Server workloads compared to recent AMD processors. Intel processors have better single-threaded performance and lower physical core counts (so the licensing costs are lower for SQL Server 2012). Even with the SQL Server Core Factor Table discount for AMD, it is pretty hard to make a case for using AMD processors for SQL Server 2012.